# Adding a new command to MIPS

Tags: mips

I was in an interview and got the following question:

> We would like to create a new MIPS command called `foo` with the following syntax:
>
> `foo rt, rs, immediate`
>
> Assume that `rt` and `rs` are not equal and `immediate` can be positive, negative or zero with a length of `16` bits.
>
> The command does the following:
>
> 1. `rt = immediate`
> 2. `rs = immediate + 4`
>
> Answer the following questions:
>
> 1. If we would like to implement this command in `single-cycle MIPS`, what minimal changes should we do? What if we want in `Multi-cycle MIPS`?
> 2. Create a pseudo-command of the with the basic `MIPS` commands to create `foo`.

I thought that the changes should be in the `ALU` only for both `single` and `multi` but I was wrong. I didn't get the opportunity to answer the second question because I blew the first one (I don't know the answer for it). I hope they will give me another chance so now I'm trying to study this material. How can I answer these questions?

Comment: it's called an [instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture), not command and no, you can't add arbitrary instructions to any non-programmable hardware. A pseudo instruction is different because it's just like macros

Comment: @phuclv it's a theoretical question meaning - look at it from the eyes of the creator. Of course we won't add this `instruction` to MIPS, just theoretically.

Comment: Just guessing, here, but for a single-cycle you'd need to add support for writing back two registers. For multi-cycle you don't need that. Implementing it with basic instructions should be trivial, you have no problems with that, right?

Answer (score 1):

For the second question, a pseudo-instruction can given by the following:

```
ADDI $rt, $0, immediate
ADDI $rs, $rt, 4
```

- First you want to set `rt` to `immediate` value, which can be done by adding a zero to the `immediate` and writing the value back to `rt`.
- Second you need need to add 4 to the `immediate` and write it back to `rs`, note that the `immediate` value is already stored in `rt` register (by the previous instruction), Now you need to take the value in `rt` and add an immediate value to it (i.e 4), and write the result back to `rs`.